# How to find out when a specific thread exits (C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem here. Is there a way to programmatically find out the moment a certain thread exits? I mean, even the VS debugger gives you that info in its Output window. I know that I simply could make my thread to raise an event but this of course leads to a problem when you spawn more than one thread, so each of them will raise that event, unless you use some toggle variable to make sure that only the first thread to reach that point in code will raise the event.

Here is the beginning of a method that is executed in multiple threads, with cancellation, pause and exit logic shown here. The problem spots of code are the calls to the event handlers (DownloadComplete, DownloadPaused and DownloadCanceled). As you can see, some of them will be executed only once by the first thread that reaches that point and then toggles related bool variables, so other threads won't raise this event again. Another big problem here is the thread exit logic, when the thread doesn't find an item to download and returns with rasing that download complete event which of course will be fired by each thread. Both of these approaches are incorrect and I currently have no any idea how to implement my intended behavior. All I need is to have a clue how to find out a way to catch the momement when the last of the all of spawned thread ends so I could raise all of the mentioned above events just once.

Please note that I have no acess to the types from the System.Threading.Tasks namespace as my project is targeted against .net 2.0. This is my very first experiece with programming something more complex than some class assignment, so I realize that this code is most likely all sorts of terrible.

Sorry for my English.

```
    private void PerformDownload()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (askedToCancel)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    if (!cancellationPerformed)
                    {
                        cancellationPerformed = true;

                        foreach (DownloadItem di in itemsToProcess)
                            if (di.Status == DownloadItemStatus.Prepared)
                                itemsToProcess.UpdateItemStatus(di.URL, DownloadItemStatus.Canceled);

                        DownloadCanceled();
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            if (askedToPause)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    if (!pausingPerformed)
                    {
                        foreach (DownloadItem di in itemsToProcess)
                            if (di.Status == DownloadItemStatus.Prepared)
                                itemsToProcess.UpdateItemStatus(di.URL, DownloadItemStatus.Paused);

                        DownloadPaused();
                    }
                }

                waitHandle.WaitOne();
            }

            DownloadItem currentItem = null;

            lock (lockObj)
            {
                foreach (DownloadItem di in itemsToProcess)
                    if (di.Status == DownloadItemStatus.Prepared)
                    {
                        currentItem = di;
                        itemsToProcess.UpdateItemStatus(currentItem.URL, DownloadItemStatus.Downloading);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            if (currentItem == null)
            {
                DownloadComplete();
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Interlocked.Increment()` and `Interlocked.Decrement()` on a counter, incrementing at the thread's entry point, decrementing when the thread exits. Then if the counter is non-zero, at least one instance of that thread is running.

For example:

```
private int _threadCounter;

private void ThreadEntryPoint()
{
    try
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadCounter);
        // Do thread stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadCounter);
    }
}
```

That said, it is IMHO not likely to be the best design for it to *matter* whether the thread is running or not. That is, whenever I think of how that information might be used, it seems to me there's a better way to address the scenario.

Threads exist for a reason, beyond simply being present. So what your code really ought to care about is whether that reason has been addressed, not whether any thread is running. Without a complete code example, I can't really comment on a specific scenario. But I suspect that tracking the actual thread existence is less useful and will be harder to maintain than a more goal-oriented approach.

Comment: Well, putting the whole code of the threaded method inside try-catch would be too much of course, but I will try to count the active threads in the way you suggest.